# django Form validation not working, why?

Tags: django, django-forms

This is my first project in django and i cant find a problem, 
Problem: submit button alow even when form is not valid
In another form .is_valid() working very good,

Maybe not working because one POST sending 2 diferent model, can be true?

idea from: http://www.joshuakehn.com/2013/7/18/multiple-django-forms-in-one-form.html
Any idea to resolve problem?

views.py

```
[...]
def reservation_view(request, pk):
    bus = get_object_or_404(Bus, pk=pk)

    form_client = ClientForm(prefix='cl')
    form_var = ReservationForm(prefix='res')

    if request.method == "POST":

        form_client = ClientForm(request.POST,prefix='cl')
        form_var = ReservationForm(request.POST,prefix='res')

        if form_var.is_valid() and form_client.is_valid():
            newreservation = form_var.save(commit=False)
            newreservation.reBusID = bus
            newreservation.reClientID = form_client.save()       #can be changed i future if the same client
            newreservation.reDate = timezone.now() #not in use right now
            newreservation.save()
        buses = Bus.objects.filter(available_for_cutomers=True)    #to dispaly next site if form is valid
        return render(request, 'busreserv/client.html', {'buses' : buses})
    else:
        form_var = ReservationForm()
        form_client = ClientForm()
        return render(request, 'busreserv/newreservation.html', {'formReservation' : form_var, 'bus':bus , 'form_client':form_client})
```

models.py

```
class Bus(models.Model): # Base model of Bus

    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    plate_nr = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    people_capacity = models.IntegerField()
    price_per_km = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    available_for_cutomers = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.plate_nr


class Client(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    clientEmail = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    clientPhone = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lastName



class Reservation(models.Model):
    reBusID = models.ForeignKey( 'Bus',blank=True, null=True)
    reClientID = models.ForeignKey( 'Client',blank=True, null=True)
    reDate = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True) #not used yet
    km = models.IntegerField()
    details = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.details
```

.html

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}

    {{ form_client.as_p }}
    {{ formReservation.as_p }}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Book it</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You need either of these forms to pass? Or what's the expected logic you want?